# If $X\times Y$ and $X$ are compact then $Y$ is also compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Our professor gave a study guide for final exam and one of the problems is the following:

If $X\times Y$ and $X$ are compact, prove that $Y$ is compact.

**Proof:** Consider the projection $\pi_2:X\times Y\to Y$ since the projection is surjective and continuous function it follows that $Y$ is compact since it is the image of compact $X\times Y$ under continuous map, right?

I believe that this reasoning is correct but as you see the condition that $X$ is compact is redundant, right?

Would be very thankful for any comments!

Comment: You are correct in saying that $X$ compact is not *needed* (in fact $X\ne \emptyset$ and $X\times Y$ compact is sufficient). However, in hindsight it is true that $X\times Y$ is compact only if either both factors are compact or one of them is empty.

Comment: @Gae.S., could you clarify your second sentence, please? I didn't get it!

Comment: My point is that most likely the person who wrote the exercise was thinking $X\times Y$ non-empty and compact, in which case $X$ compact is true, despite not being necessary in the economy of a proof that $Y$ needs to be compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Eric, the proof remains as long as $X$ is non-empty.

If you wanted a proof without using the result, proceed as follows :

- Consider an arbitrary open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $Y$.
- Show that $\{X \times U_i\}$ is an open cover of $X \times Y$.
- This has a finite subcover, say $\{X \times U_1 , ..., X \times U_n\}$.
- Show that $\{U_1,...U_n\}$ cover $Y$.
- Conclude from the arbitrary nature of the initial $\{U_i\}$.

We used nothing about $X$ here(except non-emptiness : where did we use that?).

Comment: But the proof which you've provided works also if $X$ is nonempty, right? because if $X$ is empty then there is no enough information about $Y$.

Comment: If $X$ is empty, then $X \times U_i= \emptyset$ for all $i$, so you won't be able to retrieve the $U_i$ from the finite subcover coming from $X \times Y$, which  is the problem. In other words , the correspondence $X \times U_i \leftrightarrow U_i$ is lost when $X$ is empty. That is a precise way of saying that $X$ empty implies no information about $Y$. You must tell your professor about this special case : although I am sure he will be careful enough to put non-empty in .

Comment: Am i right that if $X$ is nonempty then we do not need the compactness of $X$?

Comment: *Yes, you are right*. In particular, compactness of $X$ would also follow from compactness of $X \times Y$ simiarly anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This is correct as long as $X$ is nonempty.  If $X$ is empty then $\pi_2$ is not surjective and $Y$ does not need to be compact (it could be any space at all!).

Comment: Yes you are right! So what is the final answer in this problem? As you said if $X=\varnothing$ then we cannot say smth about $Y$.